# Cloning a Craft CMS project to XAMPP

Tags: php, git, xampp, content-management-system, craftcms

I am fairly new to git and I am looking to clone a repo to XAMPP.

From what I understand I should be able to just clone it to HTDOCS and it should work if all the dependencies are installed.

I get this error message when I visit the project folder in my browser.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function init() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\services\CacheService.php:114
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\framework\base\CModule.php(394):
>   Craft\CacheService->init() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(595):
>   CModule->getComponent('cache', true) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\framework\base\CModule.php(103):
>   Craft\WebApp->getComponent('cache') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\services\ConfigService.php(392):
>   CModule->__get('cache') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\services\HttpRequestService.php(1181):
>   Craft\ConfigService->usePathInfo() #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\services\HttpRequestService.php(131):
>   Craft\HttpRequestService->getNormalizedPath() #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\framework\base\CModule.php(394):
>   Craft\HttpRequestService->init() #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(595):
>   CModule->getComponent('request', true) #8
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\framework\base\CMo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\craft\app\services\CacheService.php on line
>   114

I know this a vague question but I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: not familiar with it but looks like you need to clear the cache, or define the cache which is used. APC, db, EAccelerator, File, MemCache, Redis, WinCache, XCache, ZendData, by the time it get to `$this->_cacheComponent->init();` .. `_cacheComponent` is null..

Comment: This is a php error and I don’t think git is involved (except for the clone part)

Comment: I'm still not having any luck with this. Think I must have installed it wrong from the start.

The first steps I was given to install this were:

**Clone repo**, 
**Copy env.example to .env**, 
**Import Database Locally**, 
**Edit database connections**.

And this is where it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I think once you will clone the craft project from your git repo. You need to add .Env file into it. Then your need "uploads" folder. Also you should run the composer install command to install all the dependencies.

After all this process if you still getting the same error then you should try to remove cache from your runtime cache folder and also you can remove compiled classes and templates once.

I hope this will work.